# Godaddy redirection for domain URL

Tags: domains, redirects, godaddy

I have mydomain.co registered with Godaddy.
In the zone editor I have the @ record pointing to my cloud server.
I would now like to redirect mydomain.co/blog to a different server
where I'll host a wordpress blog.
I cannot figure out how to do this on Godaddy.
All Godaddy support pages describe buttons that do not exist on my domain control panel.

I'm sure my question is a dupe, but I just can't find the original.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the quickest and simplest method:

Create a file 'index.php' at `mydomain.com/blog/index.php` and put this inside:

```
<?php
header('Location: http://new-wordpress.blog/');
?>
```

This will redirect all requests for `mydomain.com/blog` to the WordPress server.

Comment: Nice one ionFish this could be useful for me too, using static sites on CDN are awesome but contact pages are the problem due to PHP with this code I should be able to redirect on the contact page! n1.